# How to use two wireless modems/routers together?

Tags: router, home-networking, internet-connection, modem

I have two wireless modems/routers and one line. I want to use both at the same time to increase coverage. I know that it's not possible to run two modems at once from one line.

Is it possible to use one as a modem and the other as a router only? And if yes, how?

Comment: What are the make and model numbers of the devices? Also, you're asking the wrong question. You don't want to use the other one as a router (routers connect different networks together) but as either an access point or a repeater (which extend a single network). Do you plan to connect the two devices with a wire?

Comment: The devices are Inca IM-310NX and ZyXEL P-660HN-F1Z. And I don't need to extend a single point, they can use 2 different networks, that doesn't really matters for me. I could connect the devices with a cat5 cable but i would prefer to do it wirelessly if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1. take up your first router and link it to your pc using RG45 cable.
2. login to your router web-based utility (click WIN+R TYPE: `http://192.168.1.1` and hit enter) choose BRIDGE MODE save/restart and switch off /unplug your fist router.
3. take your second router and connect it to your pc as you did with your first router ; enter the setup and choose PPPoE MODE ,Enter Your USERNAME And LOGIN (from your ISP) Change the lan IP Address to `192.168.2.1`. Save, logout and unplug your second router.
4. take your first router again plug in your dsl cable into RG11port of your first router then connect in with your pc [don't switch it on yet] take your second router link it to your first router with RG45 after this switch them both on.
5. go to your browser enter ......an hit enter and start navigating.

You can access the internet wirelessly simply by hooking your first and second pc by means of CAT5 RG45.